# NLTK: Parsing sentences using a simple grammar and part of speech tags

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, grammar

For a sentence like "This is a simple sentence" which has been part of speech tagged to:

```
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('simple', 'JJ'), ('sentence', 'NN')]
```

And using the following grammar:

```
    my_grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
... S -> DP VP
... DP -> Det NP
... NP -> Adj N
... VP -> V DP
... Det -> 'DT'
... N -> 'NN'
... V -> 'VBZ'
... Adj -> 'JJ'
... """)
```

How do I output a tree structure. I am attempting to use the part of speech tags in place of the word that has been tagged, but still display the word itself in the tree to get something similar to:

```
    (S
     (DP This)
     (VP
      (V is)
      (DP (Det a)
       (NP
        (Adj simple) (N sentence))))
```

EDIT: I've tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858467/combining-a-tokenizer-into-a-grammar-and-parser-with-nltk?rq=1), but when I get to using the command:

```
for tree in parser.parse(pos_tags):
...     print(tree)
```

Nothing is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, if you employ the above grammar to parse the given sentence, than the parser will return nothing, since no grammar rule matches the initial `This` to the `DT` phrase.

You may add the rule: `DP -> Det`

Comment: I modified the  `DP -> Det NP` line to `DP -> Det NP | Det`. If I run the parser on the pos_tags variable like: 

`> pos_tags = [pos for (token,pos) in nltk.pos_tag(sentence)]` to get
`['DT', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN']`

It will now return `(S (DP (Det DT)) (VP (V VBZ) (DP (Det DT) (NP (Adj JJ) (N NN)))))`, but if I run it on a normal POS tagged sentence using nltk.pos_tag() on a word tokenized sentence it returns an error.

This solves my grammar error. Now on to figuring out how to get it to show the actual tagged words instead of the tags themselves. Thank you!